# How to find the disk number of the newly added using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Let's say I added a disk to my computer, how can I find newly added disks with PowerShell?

Comment: Take a look at `Get-Disk` / `Get-Volume`

Comment: How would you like to distinguish the newly added disks? Is this something you added while the computer was running? Is it brand new, as in a disk that is not yet partitioned or anything? Did you shut down your computer, plug in a hard drive from another computer, and then want to try and find the "new" drive after you boot up the machine? We need more details here.

Comment: Actually I am using you machine on a VM and I added a 10gb disk for it. It remains unformatted yet. Is there a command that specifically shows that it has just been added?

Comment: What you're probably after is `Get-Partition` then. It will probably be listed as "Unknown" under the `OperationalStatus` property. So: `Get-Partition | Where-Object -Property OperationalStatus -EQ 'Unknown'`.

Comment: Please specify "newly": newest OR all disks in a particular period of time (if so, which period)?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am using you machine on a VM and I added a 10gb disk for it. It remains unformatted yet. Is there a command that specifically shows that it has just been added?